# Making a decision between MEAN stack and Spring MVC for building a complex website

Tags: spring-mvc, mean-stack

I am just about to start building a website that has complex data-driven applications and business logic. I want the front-end to be user-friendly and I've heard lots of good things about AngularJS (especially the MEAN stack) for building user interface which could be either mobile or traditional website.

I am at this decision point: use MEAN stack with MongoDB or Spring MVC with Hibernate/MySQL. I've heard rumors that Javascript-based frameworks are not a good fit for applications that have complex business logic. As you can tell, I'm a novice to Javascript/AngularJS, but I've read a good book on AngularJS and have done some toy programs with it. My skills in Spring MVC/Hibernate are relatively better. So I am asking for opinions that could help me make a decision.

Comment: Questions that are primarily opinion-based are [not suitable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for StackOverflow. Developers will opine that could build your application with either stack, but you really need to consider your own experience as well as your project timeline and objectives. You have stacks with different programming languages, data modelling libraries, backend databases, and design idioms. Learning a new stack is generally not conducive to providing a good estimate for a complex project, but if you're scratching your own itch than it may not matter.

Answer (score 3):

There is an element of opinion here that you can't ignore, but approaching it from a more objective point of view, you need to think about the needs of your application, your own experience as a web developer and how much time you are willing to spend learning.

Firstly, the MEAN stack is JavaScript centric. So you need to be comfortable with JavaScript or at least be up for learning more about how it works and specifically how Node.js' asynchronous nature will come into play when developing your application. That being said, it is not that complicated once you wrap your head round those concepts and there is something very attractive of using very similar syntax for your database, backend and frontend layers. On the other hand, for Spring MVC, you will need to be comfortable with Java and its own idiosyncrasies.

Secondly, you need to think about your application. Regarding the database, you need to think about your access patterns and the structure of your data. Will you need transactions? Do you prefer to define your schema beforehand or have the ability to shape it as you go? All of that will weigh in when you choose between MongoDB and MySQL. And you will have to ask yourself similar questions when deciding between Java and Node.js.

So I guess the best thing to do is consider the needs of your application and consider how you want to tackle the job both in terms of what you currently know and what you want to learn. Then you can make a better decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you're for sure going with Angular then it doesn't really matter what backend you choose. I was also unfamiliar with Node and Mongo but I like trying new things so I went with [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack). The best perspective for building an Angular app is to treat it like any other client (iOS, Android, or whatever). Your web server exposes an API and serves static files, that's it.